# pyspark memory consumption is very low

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am using anaconda python and installed pyspark on top of it. In the pyspark program, I am using the dataframe as the data structure. The program goes like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
sdf = spark_session.read.orc("../data/")
sdf.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
df = spark_session.sql("select field1, field2 from data group by field1")
df.write.csv("result.csv")
```

While this works but it is slow and the memory usage is very low (~2GB). There is much more physical memory installed.

I tried to increase the memory usage by:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.executor.memory', '16g')
```

But it does not seem to help at all.

Any ways to speedup the program? Especially, how to fully utilize the system memory?

Thanks!

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your code. You are using a group by without an aggregate function. This is would give you wrong answer if there are multiple rows with same field1 value.

Comment: Thanks, it is just for demonstrating the problem. The actual query is much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use configuration for your session:

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set(spark.executor.memory', '16g')
spark_session = SparkSession.builder \
        .config(conf=conf) \
        .appName('test') \
        .getOrCreate()
```

Or run the script with `spark-submit`:

```
spark-sumbit --conf spark.executor.memory=16g yourscript.py
```

You should also probably set the `spark.driver.memory` to something reasonable.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As a newbie, I just find I am actually running it in local mode so setting spark.driver.memory worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad I helped :)